# Javascript - string + var alert

Tags: javascript, alert

I have trouble figuring out why is my alert command not working. I tried looking for an answer in other peoples' questions, but because I am a complete newbie, I was not able to find a solution. My console is giving me this error: practice.js:26 *Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list* . Thank you for any advice. I'm in my first week of JavaScript so go easy on me please :)

```
var firstName = prompt("What is your first name?");
var lastName = prompt("What is your last name?");

firstName = firstName.toUpperCase();
lastName = lastName.toUpperCase();

var fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;

var fullNameLength = fullName.length;

alert("The string " + fullName + " is " fullNameLength + " characters long.");
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error? I suspect the cause may be above this code.

Comment: Your missing an `+` at `"fullName + " is " fullNameLength"`. Note this can be closed as a typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one `+` sign in the alert parameter:

```
alert("The string " + fullName + " is " + fullNameLength + " characters long.");
//                                      ^ here
```

You should write your code in some proper editor or IDE (webstorm, vs code, ...). That way the editor will highlight those simple syntax errors for you and sometimes even suggest a solution.

Comment: Děkuji ! :) Yup, for this particular piece of code I was using the teamtreehouse workspace so it did not highlight the mistake. My bad! :)